# Executing self-contained javascript from.... javascript

Tags: javascript

I have javascript that is being generated at design time that needs to be executed to find a value at run time.  The code is stored as a string in an object and I would like to be able to execute it and retrieve the value and then scrap the code. Is there a way to do this?  Do I have to use `eval()`?

Comment: You can either use `eval()` or create a `<script>` node with the script as its contents.

Comment: What is "design time".  If the code isn't generated at runtime, why isn't it a function?

Comment: @Barmar I'm concerned about using eval since it can be hijacked easily

Comment: @Charles Salvia  Well, the code is being generated outside of the scope of my app, but prior to actually running it.  My application can't be concerned with the actual contents of the script

Comment: That's true of any method that executes user-supplied code. It's not eval that's the problem, it's the fact that you're letting the user supply code.

Comment: it's not technically user-supplied code, it's code stored in a database written by someone else and will be specifically intended for what my app needs to use it for

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval(String)`

Or use `new Function (String)`

Or use `document.createElement`

**[edited]**

Depend on how it was done your code

**1 -** 
if those strings are saved in shared across different pages (with `cookies` or `database`), then `SERVER-SIDE` you can generate a tag `<script>` with the values ​​saved in a `JSON` for quick access.

**2 -** 
If the strings are saved only at runtime (ie in pagination are not recoverable values) you may not need to save these values ​​in `Strings`, talves you can create a `global Json` in `Window Object (eg. window.MyObjectGlobal)`, making the values ​​accessible at any time on the page (since there is no paging) - is idea can also be reused in case of using the `SERVER-SIDE`, combined with `Ajax` (ajax only to save the data in your database), or `document.cookie` (but will have to use `document.createElement("script")` or `eval`)

Good luck

Comment: ok, I knew about these approaches already but I was wondering if there was any way to spin off like a separate javascript engine to execute the code like you can do in a native app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using `eval`.

However, remember `eval`is evil and it could potentially introduce security risks.
Anyway, if you know what you're doing, that's the way to go

Comment: I doubt the OP knows what they're doing, otherwise they wouldn't be asking!

Comment: true, but I warned him. He should first look up the security concerns I told him about :)